# MSIL references

Tags: .net, cil, il

In VB.NET you can add file references or project references.  For example, if you wanted to use the SQLConnection class, then you would add a reference to System.Data.SQLClient and import the namespace.

How does this work at a lower level in MSIL and assembly language.  I assume that the executable would contain all the code from System.Data.SQLClient?

I have inspected some MSIL generated from a VB.NET project, but I am still unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the executable would not include all code from `System.Data.SQLClient`. Instead the .NET runtime loads the assemblies your app references. That allows assemblies to be shared among many apps. So the running process includes the code from [`System.Data.dll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx), but your executable does not.

Comment: Isn't it more the AppDomain than the process that includes the code? (Though that distinction doesn't matter in most cases.)

Comment: The AppDomain is really just another container within the managed app. The library (module if you will) is certainly loaded at the process level.

Answer (score 2):

The system.Data assembly is loaded (because your project reference it), you can see this in the MANIFEST (ildasm)

```
.assembly extern System.Data
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
```

Call that uses SqlConnection:

```
 IL_000f:  newobj     instance void [System.Data]System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection::.ctor()
```

Defnition of .assembly extern:

```
.assembly extern <assembly name>
   Specifies another assembly that contains items referenced by the current module (in this example, mscorlib).
```

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceats605.aspx